# How to create conditional pandas series/column?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a sample df:

```
   A B C D E (New Column)
0  1 2 a n ?
1  3 3 p d ?
2  5 9 f z ?
```

If Column A == Column B PICK Column C's value apply to Column E;
Otherwise PICK Column D's value apply to Column E.

I have tried many ways but failed, I am new please teach me how to do it, THANK YOU!

Note:
It needs to PICK the value from Col.C or Col.D in this case. So there are not specify values are provided to fill in the Col.E(this is the most different to other similar questions)

Comment: So column `E` should be `n p z`, right? Please in the future provide a [mre] including desired output. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Got it and will follow the instruction, Thank you for reminding!

Answer (score 3):

use [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where)

```
df['E'] = np.where(df['A'] == df['B'],
                   df['C'],
                   df['D'])
df
```

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   2   a   n   n
1   3   3   p   d   p
2   5   9   f   z   z
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `pandas` [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

```
df['E'] = df['C'].where(df['A'].eq(df['B']), df['D'])
df
Out[570]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  a  n  n
1  3  3  p  d  p
2  5  9  f  z  z
```

Comment: Thank you! it seem 'where' is very important but i never use it...